# How to define a style which looks at a property for it's value

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have style defined for a togglebutton which sets the background color when the ToggleButton is pressed.

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Border CornerRadius="10" Margin="5,5,5,5" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This works, but what I **REALLY** want to do is to have this style set different colors, based on a property that I can define in the XAML for the togglebutton.

Is this even possible?  If so, how does one go about it?

-- 
So took Eric's answer below and it worked, but now I find myself wanting to modify both the Background and Foreground on a per instance basis.

I tried the following:

```
    public static class ToggleButtonAttach
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CheckedBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(ToggleButtonAttach));
    public static void SetCheckedBackground(ToggleButton target, Brush value) => target.SetValue(CheckedBackgroundProperty, value);
    public static Brush GetCheckedBackground(ToggleButton target) => (Brush)target.GetValue(CheckedBackgroundProperty);

    private static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedForegroundProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CheckedForeground", typeof(Brush), typeof(ToggleButtonAttach));
    public static void SetCheckedForeground(ToggleButton target, Brush value) => target.SetValue(CheckedForegroundProperty, value);
    public static Brush GetCheckedForeground(ToggleButton target) => (Brush)target.GetValue(CheckedForegroundProperty);

}


       <Style x:Key="ToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Focusable="False" CornerRadius="10" Margin="5,5,5,5" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="toggleButtonContentPresenter" TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="toggleButtonContentPresenter" Value="{Binding Path=(piapp:ToggleButtonAttach.CheckedForeground), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=(piapp:ToggleButtonAttach.CheckedBackground), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
         </Style>
```

But I am getting the following error:  "The member "CheckedForeground" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Obviously something is wrong, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, I want so set a property in the XAML for the togglebutton which is the color that I want to use for the background color for the style that is to be set when the IsChecked is true.

Comment: It sounds like you want to be able to swap out colors during run time right? I don't think that's possibly using purely xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an attached property, then you can dynamically set that to a given brush and use that brush for the background in the ControlTemplate:

**C#**

```
public static class ToggleButtonInfo
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CheckedBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(ToggleButtonInfo));

    public static void SetCheckedBackground(ToggleButton target, Brush value) => target.SetValue(CheckedBackgroundProperty, value);
    public static Brush GetCheckedBackground(ToggleButton target) => (Brush)target.GetValue(CheckedBackgroundProperty);
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wpfApp1="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Border x:Name="border"  CornerRadius="10" Margin="5,5,5,5" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=(wpfApp1:ToggleButtonInfo.CheckedBackground), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ToggleButton Content="Hello" wpfApp1:ToggleButtonInfo.CheckedBackground="{x:Static Brushes.Fuchsia}" Style="{StaticResource ToggleStyle}"></ToggleButton>
</Window>
```

Comment: Great this works.  However now I'm running into an issue where I can't create a Background and Foreground color for the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a custom control with additional [dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview). From the article:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSpinningProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IsSpinning", typeof(Boolean),
    typeof(MyCode)
    );

public bool IsSpinning
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSpinningProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsSpinningProperty, value); }
}
```

Your control template can then bind the various elements and their color properties to your respective  dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that "This works, but what I REALLY want..." I am not sure how that works without overwriting control template. 
The following code block sets the initial toggle button color to `Green` and whenever its toggled it will set the background color, which is the property you set as you like. This will give you an idea.

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Border Name="border" CornerRadius="10" Margin="5,5,5,5" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger  Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter  TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Background}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger  Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                                <Setter  TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>
```

if you want a separate property for setting toggle color, you need to follow attached property concept as others mentioned.